# Azure deployment stuck

Tags: azure, bitbucket

I have a working azure web app, I cant deploy anything when I click Deployment center it just stuck at Fetching deployment data

[image: fetching]

If I wait for while I get this:
[image]
I have to mention that I had apps before on azure and everything worked smooth.. the only difference between the apps is that the broken app I created with azure VS extension.

all the apps are configured to auto-deploy from Bitbucket

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: I deleted and recreated the app

Answer (score 1):

For me, there wasn't enough space on the disk. I saw this "lack of space" error message after clicking Deployments in Kudu (Advanced Tools in your web app). I deleted the LogFiles folder to free up space and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with deployment sticking/breaking when I was trying to use the F (free) tier. I was trying to push a .NET Core app with https: support enabled in the app. Because the F tier does not support SSL, it broke everything and there was no trace to say what the problem was. Not sure if this was your problem as well, but if anyone is trying to do the same thing that I did, I hope this is helpful.  Changing to an S (standard) tier fixed it. I suppose disabling https: support in the app you are trying to push would work as well, but I did not try that approach.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me last night. Finished up some changes to an API and front end app. API published to app service without issue from Github pipeline. Front end app would not publish. Error was:

`Deployment Failed with Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Conflict (CODE: 409)`

Same issue as here. The deploument center would never load and eventually would give me a Gateway Timeout error. Two hours I spent trying to figure out what was wrong. Even opened a support ticket. It was a problem with the Azure service that was resolved by the next morning.